# Gremlin: Count outbound edges with a given label and property value

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I have a graph where vertices have several outbound edge types and each of those edge types have properties. I want to get a count of outbound edges from each vertex but limit the count to edges with a certain label and property value.

So far I have:

```
g.V().hasLabel("vertexLabel").as("source")
    .outE("edgeLabel").has("edgeProp", "propValue").as("edge")
    .select("source", "edge")
```

This gives me a list of each source vertext and each outgoing edge with the correct label and property. What I want to do is reduce this to a single entry for each source vertex and count of the number of outbound edges. However I cannot seem to get `groupCount` to work in combination with `outE`. The closest I have got is:

```
g.V().hasLabel("vertexLabel").as("source").out("edgeLabel").groupCount()
```

This gives me count by source vertex but includes all the edges with that label regardless of what property values they have.

I know this probably needs a `group().by()` step but I am not sure how to form it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the "modern" toy graph from TinkerPop, I think you can best express this by using `project()`:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').
......1>   project('source','count').
......2>     by().
......3>     by(outE('created').has('weight',gt(0.5)).count())
==>[source:v[1],count:0]
==>[source:v[2],count:0]
==>[source:v[4],count:1]
==>[source:v[6],count:0]
```

You can do this with `groupCount()` as well but it feels a bit more awkward to me:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').
......1>   outE('created').
......2>   has('weight',gt(0.5)).
......3>   groupCount().
......4>     by(inV())
==>[v[5]:1]
```

Note you lose the "0" values in this case because the edges get filtered away prior to `groupCount()`. You could also go with `group()` but I don't think it reads as nicely as `project()`:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').
......1>   group().
......2>     by().
......3>     by(outE('created').
......4>        has('weight',gt(0.5)).count())
==>[v[1]:0,v[2]:0,v[4]:1,v[6]:0]
```

Comment: Nice answer to edge counts, thanks, helpful.